# How to create Venn digaram for 8 groups using R?

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I used following code to generate the sets:

```
H=list('ASD'=c("SCN3A", "TSC2", "RASSF8", "XDH", "CNTN5", "CHD7", "DPYD", "BUB1", "DPP4", "AMPD1", "ARID4A", "QSER1", "OCA2", "GPR141", "DNAH9", "LOXHD1", "SETX", "GSTP1", "SLC6A15", "ASTN1", "CACNA1D", "WFS1", "KCNC1", "TPRA1", "NBAS", "LAMB1", "TSNARE1", "GABRB3", "PAG1", "SOS1", "LHFPL4", "KMT2C", "GATM", "NPTX2", "ANK3", "SH3TC2", "CLPP", "TP53BP1", "EBF4", "ANO1", "DNAJC10", "TTC25", "NDUFB7", "PCSK1", "ROBO3", "MYO9A", "RPS23", "ZNF292", "CRBN", "HIVEP2", "CYP1B1", "KCNE2", "NRP2", "ADSL", "XIRP2", "SMARCA4", "HDAC2", "JAK2", "ATP9B", "ESR1", "MDN1", "CTNNA2", "CNTNAP2", "SPTB", "ACY1", "CEP290", "WNT2", "IQGAP3", "CACNG3", "CACNA1H", "FOXN1", "SPAST", "ADCY1", "IGF2", "RNF4", "CTTNBP2", "TMF1", "CPT1A", "TENM3", "RABGGTA", "MBD3", "CCDC18", "SMG1", "SYNE1", "PITX3", "HMGA2", "PDE6C", "CTU2", "PNPLA7", "PIEZO1", "MAP2", "MCF2L", "PRF1", "VWA8", "LRP2", "RYR3", "IPO9", "DIXDC1", "CNTNAP5", "ELP4", "LRRN1", "TRIO", "SACS", "ASIC2", "KIF1B", "AXIN2", "SORL1", "DLG2", "VPS13C", "F2RL1", "NRP1", "LAMA1", "LARP1", "SDK1", "LAMC2", "LSG1", "EP300", "DGCR6L", "TSHB", "APC", "TENM4", "IGSF21"),
         'Epilepsy'=c("ADCY1", "ADSL", "ANK3", "APC", "ASIC2", "ASTN1", "ATP9B", "AXIN2", "BUB1", "CACNA1D", "CACNA1H", "CACNG3", "CEP290", "CLPP", "CNTN5", "CNTNAP2", "CNTNAP5", "CTNNA2", "CTU2", "DGCR6L", "DLG2", "DNAJC10", "ELP4", "EP300", "GABRB3", "HDAC2", "HMGA2", "IGSF21", "IPO9", "IQGAP3", "JAK2", "KCNC1", "KCNE2", "KIF1B", "LAMB1", "LAMC2", "LARP1", "LHFPL4", "MCF2L", "MYO9A", "NDUFB7", "NRP2", "RABGGTA", "RYR3", "SACS", "SCN3A", "SETX", "SMARCA4", "SMG1", "SORL1", "SPAST", "SPTB", "TMF1", "TP53BP1", "TPRA1", "TRIO", "TSC2", "TSHB", "VPS13C", "WFS1", "XDH", "ZNF292", "ABCA1", "ABCG5", "ACP2", "ADCY6", "ADGRA3", "ADGRV1", "AGA", "AGRN", "ALG3", "ANK2", "ANKRD44", "AP5Z1", "ARAP1", "ARHGEF11", "ASCC3", "ASPM", "ATRN", "AURKB", "BRINP2", "BRSK2", "CAPN15", "CAPN2", "CC2D2A", "CD36", "CDX1", "CHAT", "CHM", "CHTF18", "CLCN2", "CLCN7", "CLEC12A", "COG5", "COG6", "COL12A1", "COL17A1", "COL28A1", "COL6A2", "COQ3", "CYBB", "DBNL", "DBR1", "DEAF1", "DGKQ", "DHX29", "DMXL1", "DMXL2", "DNAH12", "DOCK7", "DOLK", "DSG4", "DZIP1", "EFHC1", "EPHA7", "EPHB1", "EPHB3", "ESYT1", "EXOC7", "F13A1", "F5", "FAH", "FARP1", "FASN", "FAT1", "FERMT1", "FGFR3", "FLNB", "FLRT1", "FMNL1", "FN1", "FOLR1", "FZD4", "GAA", "GAK", "GALC", "GANAB", "GLB1", "GM2A", "GNA14", "GOSR2", "GPC1", "GSS", "GTPBP4", "HEATR1", "HGS", "HIPK2", "HSPA13", "HTR2B", "INO80E", "KALRN", "KCNH2", "KCNJ16", "KIAA0586", "KRIT1", "LAMB2", "LMAN1", "LTBP3", "MASTL", "MED17", "METTL25", "MGAT5B", "MPL", "MRPL24", "MRPS27", "MSX2", "MUS81", "NALCN", "NEB", "NFE2L1", "NMBR", "NOL11", "NUCB1", "OBSL1", "OGDHL", "OGFOD2", "PARP1", "PCCB", "PDGFRA", "PDYN", "PFAS", "PFKFB3", "PLEC", "PLOD2", "PNKD", "PNPO", "POLD1", "POLE", "POLL", "PPAT", "PRDX3", "PSEN2", "PTCH1", "PTK2B", "RAB5A", "RAD54B", "RELB", "RHOT2", "RIMS2", "RTN4IP1", "SAE1", "SCAPER", "SCN1B", "SCN5A", "SEC23IP", "SERPINE2", "SGCB", "SIGLEC1", "SLC18A3", "SLC26A4", "SLC2A1", "SLC4A1", "SLC4A3", "SLITRK6", "SPG11", "STARD13", "STT3A", "SYF2", "SYNJ1", "SZT2", "TECPR2", "TES", "TMEM67", "TNK2", "TNS1", "TNS3", "TRAP1", "TRAPPC11", "TRAPPC8", "TRIP10", "TRPM2", "TRPM3", "TRPV1", "TUBGCP6", "TYW1", "UNC13B", "USP45", "VCP", "WDR62", "WWOX", "YAP1", "ZBTB48", "ZFHX4", "ZW10"),
         'Intellectual'=c("YAP1", "TSC2", "FMNL1", "MADD", "KRIT1", "TNK2", "NUP155", "COG6", "TRAPPC8", "IPO9", "CCT8", "ZFYVE16", "FAT1", "SLC37A1", "KAT6B", "WWOX", "PTK2B", "CNTNAP5", "HEATR1", "TRAPPC11", "ARID4A", "ADGRV1", "GPC1", "AURKB", "TTC39B", "GSS", "GANAB", "RFWD3", "CUL9", "SAE1", "CACNG3", "SMC4", "ASIC2", "SYF2", "PFAS", "GAK", "METTL25", "OGDHL", "RAB5A", "VPS13C", "FGFR3", "KCNC1", "DDOST", "CTNND1", "ATRN", "UNC13B", "FASN", "MYO18A", "TMF1", "CRBN", "FLNB", "LARP1", "RCC2", "MASTL", "ADGRA3", "SCAPER", "SZT2", "LRP4", "SMG1", "SYNE1", "ADCY6", "RNGTT", "EP300", "ARAP1", "ANKRD44", "VPS39", "DGCR6L", "STT3A", "COG5", "NFE2L1", "SLC7A2", "ASCC3", "LMAN1", "OBSL1", "KIF20B", "PNPLA7"),
         'Schizophrenia'=c("CRB1", "FBXW4", "CNTN5", "CHM", "DPYD", "BUB1", "DPP4", "ADGRV1", "GPC1", "DLD", "RBM19", "ITIH1", "ADCY7", "KCNC1", "ACBD5", "ELF1", "TSNARE1", "GABRB3", "TMEM182", "STT3A", "KMT2C", "ANK3", "SAMD4A", "NALCN", "PDLIM5", "LIMA1", "DYNC1I2", "TMEM26", "ANK2", "GRIN3A", "EPHB1", "BRINP2", "KALRN", "MICAL2", "TTLL6", "ZNF292", "SERPINB1", "SCAPER", "KCNS3", "VAMP1", "HDAC2", "DLG1", "CFAP58", "JAK2", "ESR1", "EFCAB14", "CNTNAP2", "PENK", "WWOX", "GLT8D1", "SFMBT2", "EEFSEC", "PDZD8", "GALC", "CACNG3", "SPG7", "ADCY1", "CLDN10", "TENM3", "OTOS", "CAPN2", "LRP4", "SYNE1", "HMGA2", "APOL4", "ARAP1", "DOPEY1", "EPN2", "MCF2L", "PLAA", "RYR3", "CNTNAP5", "POLE", "TRIO", "RAB11FIP5", "BNIP3L", "RUNX1", "AXIN2", "KIF1B", "DLG2", "MAP3K9", "CERCAM", "VPS13C", "MYO18B", "NRP1", "IRS1", "MANEA", "EP300", "DGCR6L", "TSHB", "AASDHPPT", "TRAPPC3", "APC", "TENM4"),
         'ADHD'=c("TSC2", "CSMD2", "ANK3", "ASPM", "CNTN5", "TP53BP1", "CNTNAP2", "CHD7", "GLT8D1", "CNTNAP5", "SFMBT2", "MLH1", "FLII", "PTCH1", "SPRED1", "ARHGEF12", "CHMP7", "SVEP1", "CREB5", "MSH6", "TTLL8", "DLG2", "MICAL2", "DNAH3", "ADGRA3", "ACBD5", "SYNE1", "NUCB1", "NRP2", "TMEM182", "STT3A", "GNE", "PAX5", "TENM4"),
         'Biopolar Disoder'=c("CSMD2", "ANK3", "NUMB", "CNTN5", "CTNNA2", "CNTNAP2", "NALCN", "RDH14", "WWOX", "GLT8D1", "SFMBT2", "SPRED1", "ADAMTS14", "TTC39B", "SVEP1", "COL28A1", "PDZD8", "GALC", "SORL1", "ITIH1", "CLSPN", "SLCO4A1", "VPS13C", "MYO18B", "TTLL6", "CRBN", "NFATC2", "SYNE1", "INTS7", "TMEM182", "STT3A", "WSCD1", "KCNS3", "PDGFRA"),
         'circadian'=c("YTHDC2", "LRP1B", "SAMD4A", "VTA1", "NALCN", "F13A1", "SLC4A1", "TMEM26", "ADAMTS14", "COL28A1", "RNF19A", "BRINP2", "TRHR", "CCBE1", "CACNA2D3", "MYO18A", "SLC26A7", "FRAS1", "EP300", "GNE", "LMAN1", "NMBR", "TGFBI", "CHAT", "HIPK2", "SERPINE2", "RELB", "ARHGEF12", "SETX", "CACNA1D", "ADCY7", "NBAS", "GPR83", "LTBP3", "GABRB3", "HMBS", "PSMA4", "MADD", "SIX3", "EPHB1", "GAK", "SPRY4", "ABCA13", "SLC8A3", "HIVEP2", "FAH", "ADCY6", "MYLIP", "NFE2L1", "PRKAG1", "HDAC2", "TNS1", "GSS", "CACNA1H", "POLL", "CPT1A", "CAPN2", "PITX3", "NFE2L3", "PNPLA7", "AGA", "STX16", "TNK2", "PRF1", "RYR3", "DIXDC1", "PSEN2", "SREBF1", "POLE", "RAB11FIP5", "KIF1B", "RAB5A", "NGB", "ARHGEF11", "SIX6", "SDK1", "AATK", "CYP7A1", "CUL9"),
         'dementia'=c("LMAN1", "PRDX3", "NPLOC4", "PSEN2", "ZFYVE16", "CHAT", "PENK", "LTBP1", "SNCAIP", "NOL11", "GANAB", "DLD", "SPG11", "IGSF21", "RNF19A", "ASIC2", "ASTN1", "SORL1", "SPRY4", "VCP", "TATDN1", "RAB5A", "VPS13C", "GM2A", "IRS1", "PSMB4", "NGB", "F2RL1", "RAB38", "SMOX", "PARP1", "ABCC9", "RPN2", "CAPN2", "GALNT7", "SMG1", "TBK1", "MASP2", "GNE", "GTPBP4", "CCT8", "CD63", "PSMA4", "TUBA4A", "CUL9")
        )
venn(H)
```

Throws me an error:

> Error in drawVennDiagram(data = counts, small = small, showSetLogicLabel = showSetLogicLabel, : Venn diagrams for  8  dimensions are not yet supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with package `venneuler`.
The data must first be restructured. A `lapply` loop will create data.frames with element name and set as 1st and 2nd columns, respectively. Then they are `rbind`ed and the diagram is created.

```
library(venneuler)

Hmat <- lapply(seq_along(H), \(i) {
  Set <- names(H)[i]
  data.frame(Element = H[[i]], Set)
})
Hmat <- do.call(rbind, Hmat)
vd <- venneuler(Hmat)
plot(vd)
```

[image]

---

A double `sapply` loop is a way to get the overlap counts.

```
overlap <- function(x, y) length(intersect(x, y))
sapply(H, function(h1) sapply(H, function(h2) overlap(h1, h2)))
```

Comment: I have tried this. But got an error ```Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:30: unexpected input
1: Hmat <- lapply(seq_along(H), \
                                 ^
Traceback:```

Comment: @svp You are probably running a version of R prior to 4.1.0 when the new lambdas, `\(i)`, were introduced. Try the older one, `function(i)`.

Comment: this works!!!. Also, is it possible to get the count of overlap between the sets. For example between `ASD` and `Epilepsy` there are `58` overlap

Comment: @svp Are you sure it's `58`? I'm getting `62` overlaps. `intersect(H$ASD, H$Epilepsy)` has length `62`. See the edit with a way to get the overlap counts.

Comment: Ya, `62` is it possible to put it on the venn diagram

Comment: @svp  `venneuler` returns the circles' centers and diameters, so yes, it is possible to put the counts in the diagram but it will become unreadable with 36 numbers on it, one per intersection.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I know this is not on topic, but is `\(i)` just syntactic sugar? Or is there more happening under the hood?

Comment: @Dunois `apply` loops are syntatic sugar, so, yes, I believe it's just a short-hand for `function(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ggvenn` package,

```
library(ggvenn)
ggvenn(H)
```

[image]

Comment: I have 8 groups. They show only 4 groups?

Comment: The `ggvenn` documentation doesn't say this explicitly, but if you look into the code for the function `ggvenn`, the code can only handle 2, 3, or 4 groups. I haven't been able to find a package that can handle more than 4 groups, so I use the package `UpSetR` in those cases.